# Pasar a otra Activity

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

estoy intentando pasar a otra activity que nombre (RegistroActivity) con un boton, pero al intentarlo me deja en la activity principal, hice una prueba pasado a otras Activitys y si lo permite sin problema, nose por que no ingresa especificamente a esa activity que nombre "Registroactivity".

Esta es la Activity donde esta el boton

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private SignInButton signInButton;
    public static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 777;
    Button admin;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        admin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.admin);
        admin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, RegistroActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

Esta la activity que deseo pasar

```
public class RegistroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
        Button contrasena = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contrasena);
        contrasena.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String usuario = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario)).getText().toString();
                String password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contrasena)).getText().toString();
                if (usuario.equals("admin")&& password.equals("1234"))
                {
                    startActivity (new Intent(RegistroActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });


    }
}
```

No se si tenga que ver que Registro me esta saliendo un tipo de advertencia cosa que no sucede con las demas, según esta imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esta declarada en el manifest la RegistroActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Debes registrar la `Activity` dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    ...
    ...

    <activity android:name="RegistroActivity"/> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta  ya quedo solucionado